# Problem: sending object in post request from angular to springboot

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, post, http-status-code-404

I have a problem when I trying to send an object from form in angular to springboot and MySQL database. I encouter an error 404 not found. My code is below. Here is angular service code:

```
import { DonatorDTO } from '../models/donatorDTO';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DonatorsService {
    private watKrewDonationUrl = "http://localhost:8080/donators";

    constructor(private _http: HttpClient){}

    public addDonator(donatorDTO: DonatorDTO): Observable<DonatorDTO>{
        return this._http.post<DonatorDTO>(this.watKrewDonationUrl, donatorDTO);
    }
}
```

Here is angular component code:

```
import { DonatorDTO } from './../../models/donatorDTO';

import { DonatorsService } from './../../services/donators.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, NgForm, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-donators',
  templateUrl: './donators.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./donators.component.css']
})
export class DonatorsComponent implements OnInit {

  donatorForm: NgForm;

  constructor(private donatorService: DonatorsService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  donatorDTO: DonatorDTO = new DonatorDTO();
  companies: string [] =['1. kompania','2. kompania','3. kompania','4. kompania','5. kompania','6. kompania','7. kompania','8. kompania',
                        '9. kompania','10. kompania','11. kompania','12. kompania','13. kompania','14. kompania','15. kompania','16. kompania',
                        '17. kompania','18. kompania','19. kompania','20. kompania','21. kompania'];
  bloodGroups: string [] = ['A+', 'A-', 'B+', 'B-', 'AB+', 'AB-', '0+', '0-'];
  ranks: string [] = ['szer. pchor.', 'st. szer. pchor.', 'kpr. pchor.', 'st. kpr. pchor.', 'plut. pchor.', 'sierż. pchor.'];

  createDonator() {
    console.log(this.donatorDTO);
    this.donatorService.addDonator(this.donatorDTO).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
    })
  }
  
}
```

Here is .html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl-PL">
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form #donatorForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit) = "createDonator()" >
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class = "form-control" [(ngModel)]="donatorDTO.name"  name="name" placeholder="np. Jan"  >
                    <small id="nameHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Podaj imię dawcy</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class = "form-control" [(ngModel)]="donatorDTO.surname"  name="surname" placeholder="np. Kowalski"  >
                    <small id="surnameHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Podaj nazwisko dawcy</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class = "form-control" [(ngModel)]="donatorDTO.email"  name="email" placeholder="np. jan.kowalski@wp.pl" >
                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Podaj email na którego dawca będzie otrzymywał wiadomości związane z HDK</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
               <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="donatorDTO.militaryRank" name="militaryRank">
                   <option *ngFor="let rank of ranks" [ngValue]="rank">{{rank}}</option>
               </select>
                <small id="rankHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Podaj stopień wojskowy</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <select [(ngModel)]="donatorDTO.companyName"  name="company" >
                    <option *ngFor="let cmp of companies" [ngValue]="cmp">{{cmp}}</option>
                </select>
                <small id="companyHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Wybierz pododdział dawcy</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select [(ngModel)]="donatorDTO.bloodGroup" name="bloodGroup" >
                        <option *ngFor="let blood of bloodGroups" [ngValue]="blood">{{blood}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class = "btn btn-success"  type="submit">Dodaj dawcę do bazy</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is model component:

```
export class DonatorDTO {
    name: string;
    surname: string;
    email: string;
    militaryRank: string;
    companyName: string;
    bloodGroup: string;
}
```

And now springboot service code:

```
public void addDonator(DonatorDTO donatorDTO) throws MailException {
        if (donatorRepository.existsByEmail(donatorDTO.getEmail())) {
            throw new RuntimeException("User with this e-mail already exists in db");
        } else {
            Donator donator = new Donator();
            Company company = companyRepository.findByCompanyName(donatorDTO.getCompanyName()).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Company not found"));
            BloodGroup blood = bloodGroupRepository.findBloodGroupByBloodType(donatorDTO.getBloodGroup()).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Blood group not found"));
            donator.setName(firstLetterToUpperCase(donatorDTO.getName()));
            donator.setSurname(firstLetterToUpperCase(donatorDTO.getSurname()));
            donator.setEmail(donatorDTO.getEmail());
            donator.setMilitaryRank(donatorDTO.getMilitaryRank());
            donator.setCompany(company);
            donator.setBloodGroup(blood);
            blood.setNumberOfDonators(blood.getNumberOfDonators() + 1);
            donator.setNextDonationDate(LocalDate.now());
            donator.setIsCapable(true);
            donatorRepository.save(donator);
            try {
                mailService.helloNotification(donatorDTO);
            } catch (MailException mailException) {
                logger.error("Can't send email with confirmation of addition donator in a database");
                logger.error(mailException.getMessage());
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Controller code:

```
@RestController
public class DonatorController {

    private final DonatorService donatorService;
    private final MailService mailService;

    public DonatorController(DonatorService donatorService, MailService mailService) {
        this.donatorService = donatorService;
        this.mailService = mailService;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/donators")
    public ResponseEntity addDonator(@RequestBody DonatorDTO donatorDTO) {
        donatorService.addDonator(donatorDTO);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

And here is DonatorDTO in springboot

```
package com.example.watkrew.dto;

import com.example.watkrew.entity.BloodGroup;
import com.example.watkrew.entity.Company;
import com.example.watkrew.entity.Donator;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DonatorDTO {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String email;
    private String militaryRank;
    private String companyName;
    private String bloodGroup;

    public DonatorDTO(String name, String surname, String email, String militaryRank, Company company, BloodGroup bloodGroup) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.email = email;
        this.militaryRank = militaryRank;
        this.companyName = company.getCompanyName();
        this.bloodGroup = bloodGroup.getBloodType();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you debug the server-side code? You are indeed throwing `ResourceNotFoundException` if the company or blood group cannot be found in the DB. Alternatively, make sure your `application.properties` file has `server.error.include-message=always` to send the exception message on the client side, maybe this way you can see what is actually wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, after adding your advice to application.properties there is no extra message what is wrong and is still the same message.